# JEST & Supertest Testing NodeJS. 404 Error

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

I continue to get a 404 error when running **npm run test**. In my first test, I am trying to retrieve the list of jobs from my mongoose server, however it looks like its not even able to reach api/jobs. But I checked Postman and have no issues getting the data from api/jobs. Any ideas?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const request = require("supertest");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "../.env" });
const apps = require("../app");


beforeEach(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);
  });
  
  /* Closing database connection after each test. */
  afterEach(async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  });

  describe("GET /api/jobs/", () => {
    it("should get all the jobs", async () => {
      const token = await request(apps).post("/api/users/login").send({
        email: process.env.EMAIL,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      });
  
      const response = await request(apps)
        .get("/api/jobs")
        .set({
          Authorization: "bearer " + token.body.token,
          
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        });
        
  
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
  });
```

Comment: There's nowhere in this unit test that you are starting the app. Are you using a test runner that will do this automatically for you?

Comment: Show the code of the `app` module